# How to extract a line from text file that is digits-only?

Tags: python, string, text-files

I'm having issues with a text file (subtitles) , that are easily resolvable if I can add a next line character ("\n") in every line that is only a number.

```
00:03:25,601 --> 00:03:27,468
Lorem Ipsum
94
00:03:27,470 --> 00:03:29,570
Dolor Sit Amet
95
```

Every couple of lines, there's a line with a cardinal number, that I'd either like to get rid of, or insert a newline character so my subtitles can display normally. Is it doable?

Edit: Please, allow me to rephrase my question:
I have a huge textfile which is autogenerated and it looks like this:

```
129
00:05:04,967 --> 00:05:08,936
Lorem Ipsum
130
00:05:08,938 --> 00:05:11,538
Dolor Sit Amet
131
00:05:11,540 --> 00:05:13,941
Lorem Ipsum
132
00:05:13,943 --> 00:05:16,577
Dolor Sit Amet
133
00:05:19,215 --> 00:05:20,314
Lorem Ipsum
134
00:05:20,316 --> 00:05:21,415
More Random Text
135
```

It goes like this way past 500. I Can't really show much of my code as I can't really do much with external files. I can import it and split it by lines like so:

```
with open("test.txt") as t:
    tr = t.read()
    tr_split = trr.split("\n")
```

But I can't really figure out what to do next.

Comment: Please show the code that fails to insert those newlines. Are you trying to insert them before or after these values? BTW, the answer to your current question *Is it doable?* - Yes.

Comment: You tagged this [Python]. But where's your Python code?

Comment: Added "some" code. It's not every 3rd line. Thank you for your most valuable feedback. You're gentlemen and scholars /s

Comment: That looks like `srt`?, perhaps use the `pysrt` library instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list of lines skipping the digit ones this way :

```
lines = [line for line in data.splitlines() if not line.strip().isdigit()]
```

assuming `data` is your text file content.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    t=f.read()
print re.sub(r'(\n\d+\n)','\\1\n',t)
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works.